# Does repeating the nightfall and weekly heroic strike count towards the Bad Juju bounty?

Tags: destiny

I've asked about repeating the nightfall in a previous question, but now I want to know if repeating the nightfall will add to my Bad Juju bounty. Each nightfall counts as 3 strikes I believe, so re-running the nightfall might be a quicker option if it counts towards the bounty more than once a week!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, repeating Nightfalls strikes should give you 3 every time.  Just a heads up, the weekly heroic (even at the lowest level setting) gives you 2 every time.  [This guy did 13 weekly heroics.](http://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/2itzq0/tips_for_people_with_the_bad_juju_bounty_tolands/)  Given that the weekly heroic has matchmaking now and is more forgiving, you may be better off doing weekly heroics if you don't have a group.

However, I would **only** recommend doing this method when there is an element burn, as the nightfall/heroics are much slower than a normal strike without them (Read: I wouldn't bother trying to do 8 nightfalls or 12 heroics this week on one of the longer strikes [Cerberus Vae III / Valus Ta'aurc]).

The fastest method is probably to find 2 others and do the Nexus Strike at level 14 over and over.  It can be done in about ~5-7 minutes a run, with a good group.  If you get a Nexus nightfall/heroic with a burn that'd probably be the fastest way.